# Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532) after do check for object

Tags: typescript

I am getting this error `Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)`

this is my config

```
export interface IDataColumns {
  name: string;
  label: string;
  display: string;
  empty: boolean;
  filter: boolean;
  sort: boolean;
  print: boolean;
  searchable: boolean;
  download: boolean;
  viewColumns: boolean;
  sortCompare?: null;
  sortThirdClickReset: boolean;
  sortDescFirst: boolean;
  filterType?: string | null;
  setCellProps?: () => {
    style: SxProps<Theme>;
  };
}
```

Here is my code I am doing a check for `setCellProps` before calling the function but I am getting this error `Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)` anyone know how to solve this?

```
    const styles = () => {
        if (props.columns[index].setCellProps) {
            const style = props.columns[index].setCellProps();
         return style.style;
        }
      return {};
    };
```

Comment: see [ms/TS#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530) and the answers to the linked question.  TypeScript can't narrow the type for `arr[idx]` when `idx` is a variable.  A workaround is to copy it into its own variable, like `const v = props.columns[index]` and then `if (v.setCellProps) { v.setCellProps(); }`.  Of course at that point you could do things like `props.columns[index].setCellProps?.().style ?? {}`.  Your code isn't really a [mre] so I can't check if that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without line numbers in your example, I'd suspect one of two problems.

```
   const styles = () => {
        if (props.columns[index].setCellProps) {
            const style = props.columns[index].setCellProps();
            //                               ^ Typescript isn't tracking that you just accessed props.columns[index] in the if statement above
         return style.style;
            // or setCellProps can sometimes return null, although the interface you posted seem to suggest this isn't the case.
        }
      return {};
    };
```

Possible solutions

```
   const styles = () => {
        const setCellProps = props.columns[index].setCellProps
        if (setCellProps) {
            const style = setCellProps();
            if (style) {
               return style.style;
            }
        }
      return {};
    };
```